# Update column data without using temporary tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

There is a table called `EMP`, and a column called `Gender`, which is defined as `VARCHAR(1)`, so 'M' for male and 'F' for female. A developer accidentally changed 'M' to 'F' and 'F' to 'M'.

How do you correct this without using a temptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE emp
SET    gender = CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 'F' ELSE 'M' END
```

EDIT:
The above statement assumes, for simplicity's sake, that `'M'` and `'F'` are the only two options - no `null`s, no unknowns, no nothing. A more robust query could eliminate this assumption and just strictly replace `M`s and `F`s leaving other possible values untouched:

```
UPDATE emp
SET    gender = CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 'F' 
                            WHEN 'F' THEN 'M'
                            ELSE gender
                END
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these 3 update statements:

```
update EMP set gender='X' where gender='M';
update EMP set gender='M' where gender='F';
update EMP set gender='F' where gender='X';
```